# How can escape '%' not need operator in sass?

Tags: sass

I have the following operation sass make a loop in one of their attributes and want to be a percentage width% but the output is very different

```
//h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
$i: 6;
@while $i > 0 {
    h#{$i} {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 1px + $i;


padding-right: 1px + $i;
    &::before {
        background: $color-ternary;
        content: "";
        display: block;
        height: 1px;
        position: absolute;
        width: #{$i}'%';
        bottom: 0;
        left: $i px;
    }
}
$i: $i - 1;
```

}
the output

```
  width: 1"%";
```

the expectatives

```
  width: 1%;
  width: 2%;
  width: 3%;
```

etc...

Comment: that does not solve my problem, only serves to px units if I apply the same logic returns the following. ouput   width: 10%; its not correct.

Comment: You're doing something wrong then.   The only way Sass would generate 10% is if your expression is `10 * 1%`.